# Adding parameter to express route, retrieves the opposite

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am passing a parameter for an api call to my express, but when I retrieve the json data it returns everything but what matches the query.

Here is the controller for finding the userid in my UserVote api:

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
  UserVote.find({userid: req.query.userid}, function(err, user_votes){
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    return res.json(200, user_votes);
  })
};
```

My route is as follows:

```
router.get('/ui/:userid', controller.list);
```

A sample of the json when I call the api without parameters /api/uservotes:

```
{"_id":"1","billid":"233","stance":"yea"},{"_id":"2","userid":"5524c71ba13d792907d47c14","billid":"234","stance":"yea"},{"_id":"3","userid":"5524","billid":"234","stance":"yea"},
```

and with parameters api/uservotes/ui/5524c71ba13d792907d47c14:

```
{"_id":"1","billid":"233","stance":"yea"}
```

Comment: Change `{userid: req.query.userid}` to `{userid: req.params.userid}`. You are matching on essentially `{userid: undefined}` right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to get the userid parameter the wrong way. You are defining the parameter as a route parameter but you are trying to access it as a query parameter.  Instead of req.**query**.userid, you want to use req.**params**.userid, like this:

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
  UserVote.find({userid: req.params.userid}, function(err, user_votes){
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    return res.json(200, user_votes);
  })
};
```

Comment: `req.params.userid` (plural) :-)

Comment: Thank you I see the distinction of params and query